# Avalonia MessageBox Input как получить текст с текстового поля

Tags: c#, avalonia

У меня есть такой код

```html
  var box = MsBox.Avalonia.MessageBoxManager.GetMessageBoxCustom(
                new MessageBoxCustomParams()
                {
                    ContentTitle = "Введите имя задачи",
                    Width = 400,
                    Height = 120,
                    WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner,
                    ButtonDefinitions = new List<ButtonDefinition>
                    {
                        new ButtonDefinition { Name = "Yes", },
                        new ButtonDefinition { Name = "No", }
                    },
                    InputParams = new InputParams()
                    {
                        Label = "Введите имя задачи:",
                        // DefaultValue = "dadada"
                    }
                });
            var result = box.ShowAsync();
```

Мне нужно получить текст с текстового поля, но result.Result возвращает только текст нажатой кнопки у MessageBox.

Comment: `box.InputValue`?

Comment: item создается только без текста, я продебажил и вижу что метод заканчивается без ожидания inputValue

Comment: что мне делать?

Comment: что-то я такого не нашел в исходниках https://github.com/AvaloniaCommunity/MessageBox.Avalonia/tree/master/MsBox.Avalonia

Answer (score 0):

ну да дело на много проще
у Вас на руках MsBox

```
public class MsBox<V, VM, T> : IMsBox<T> where V : UserControl, IFullApi<T>, ISetCloseAction where VM : ISetFullApi<T>, IInput
{
    private readonly V _view;
    private readonly VM _viewModel;

    public string InputValue { get { return _viewModel.InputValue; } }

    public MsBox(V view, VM viewModel)
    {
        _view = view;
        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Show messagebox depending on the type of application
    /// If application is SingleViewApplicationLifetime (Mobile or Browses) then show messagebox as popup
    /// If application is ClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime (Desktop) then show messagebox as window
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="NotSupportedException"></exception>
    public Task<T> ShowAsync()
    {
        if (Application.Current != null &&
            Application.Current.ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
        {
            return ShowWindowAsync();
        }

        if (Application.Current != null &&
            Application.Current.ApplicationLifetime is ISingleViewApplicationLifetime lifetime)
        {
            return ShowAsPopupAsync(lifetime.MainView as ContentControl);
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException("ApplicationLifetime is not supported");
    }
```

и по окончании **ShowAsync** загляните в **InputValue**

Comment: я так и не понял как это сделать

Comment: Что тут понимать? Вызывайте свой мессаж бокс нажимайте на кнопку. После проверки состояния. Посмотрите на значение в поле Input value в мессаж боксе который вы вызвали SowAsync